How to follow user on X?
My code:
def follow_user(username):
    driver.get(f"https://x.com/{username}")
    time.sleep(2)
    follow = EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Follow"]'))
    follow.click()  

got error:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'click'

Can anyone help?
Tried By.CSS_SELECTOR, same error.

EC.element_to_be_clickable returns a function to be passed to e.g. wait.until, not an element wrapper with a click method: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html.

could you paste an exaple ?

You should wrap it up with WebDriverWait:
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

def follow_user(username):
    driver.get(f"https://x.com/{username}")
    time.sleep(2)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    follow = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Follow"]')))
    follow.click()


Could you share the end of the error? I tested the code locally, it seems to be working on my side.

Works great need to change langeage there is no "Follow" button in Romanian.

Great, glad if it helped. Feel free to vote and accept the answer :)
